# How is a slack webhook safe?

Tags: security, webhooks, slack, slack-api

I'm setting up slack alerts on a project I'm working on.
To use slack's [Incoming web hook](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks), all you have to do is do a `POST` request to a slack url. I don't see any security on it. How is this secure? Wouldn't someone be able to post messages if he gets hold of this url, given that the url is public even in https connections ?

Answer (score 8):

The docs you linked say:

> **Keep it secret, keep it safe.** Your webhook URL contains a secret. Don't share it online, including via public version control repositories. Slack actively searches out and revokes leaked secrets.

That is, you should keep the webhook URL as secret as any secret (database passwords, ...) in your app.

Comment: Okay, makes sense..though there's the question of the secret (the url) being routed through public internet. It's like your password being part of a url's path param..what are your thoughts on this?

Comment: The main issue with placing secrets in paths or query parameters is that they tend to stick around in access logs. Other than that, my thoughts here are "HTTPS". No router or proxy on the public internet will be able to decipher the TLS session without consent.